# Deleting first node of linked list (C++)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to know whether this code deletes the first node correctly or should I necessarily pass list's head as a pointer?

```
 void List::deleteFirst()          
 {
 temp = head;
 head = head->next;
 delete temp;
 }
```

This is the class `List`

```
  class List
  {
   private:
           struct node
           {
                int data;
                node * next;
           };
           node * head;
           node * curr;
           node * temp;
   public:
           //List();
           //void AddNode(int addData);
           //void DeleteNode(int delData);
           void deleteFirst();
           //void PrintList();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This will work, bit only if:

- Your Nodes are allocated using `new`
- You ensure that `head` always points to a valid node (the list is not empty).

Otherwise, you will cause undefined behavior.

But you really shouldn't store `temp` as a member variable, it should be a local variable instead.

The same goes for the `curr` variable, make sure it really needs to be a member.

Also, if you delete an object (e.g. your node), all remaining pointers to it become invalid, so be careful that you don't try to access it afterwards, for ex. through the `curr*` pointer.

Answer (score -2):

Yup that will delete the the data pointed to by the original value of head.